# ElasticSearch 8 SearchScript deprecated

Tags: elasticsearch, deprecated, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to migrate "SearchScript" java class for elasticsearch existing in version 6 to version 8. But this class is deprecated in version 8.

what class could replace it?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `SearchScript` class has been [removed in 7.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/34730) and replaced by another one [called `ScoreScript`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/34730/commits/cda7be8aea20b4507607c9509d2559044fb5bcf3)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

It works for a lot of methods. But not for this one :

I now have a problem using the postings function; reader() is not recognized.

```
LeafReaderContext context; 

Postings = context.reader().postings(new Term(a,b));
```